# How to make colspan work without affecting width of the other rows

Tags: html, css

I noticed that the content of a *td* with a colspan over all columns affects the width of the other rows *td*.

Can anyone please explain me why this is and how I can get this working properly?
I have two requirements

- The first row's second column should take as much space as possible (expand)
- The second row should take 100% width, using a colspan=2 in the example

**Note**: I was playing around with some CSS properties and figured out *word-break:break-all* would fix the issue, but I would like to understand this one and/or have a better solution.

Here is the example with a longer text:

```html
<table border="1">
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col style="width:100%">            
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>Take as much space as possible, expand</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here the result with a shorter text, you can see the first row is different now.

```html
<table border="1">
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col style="width:100%">            
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>Take as much space as possible, expand</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">shorter</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Side notes - there are only two cols, but you defined three.

Comment: Both examples look identical to me in Firefox 43.0.3. What browser are you using?

Comment: Please checkout the samples, the first rows column's width changes.

Comment: Thanks @Pangloss, fixed it. Still the same. Forgot to clean it up when copying the colgroup from my code

Comment: On Chrome and Edge I have the same issue. On Firefox it behaves as expected.

Comment: For future users to know, please accept an answer, if any, that solve your question best.

Comment: @LGSon, I know, I was just hoping to get another answer.

Comment: Of course, didn't meant to rush you :) ... and thanks for the accept ... and if you in any way have any comments on an answer, feel free to comment on them and ask if there is another way. There normally always is and asking, maybe with another angle, might help and give you a second approach or answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table` is maybe the most odd element of them all and has historical cause issues cross browser and I can't say why it behaves different in different browser, it just does.

In your case, setting a small width on the first `td` will help solve your issue.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:5%">
    <col style="width:95%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>Take as much space as possible, expand</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border="1">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:5%">
    <col style="width:95%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>Take as much space as possible, expand</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">short</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```