# Why table cells width are depends on dynamic content of another inner table in Chrome 69?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have noticed strange behavior of table cells width in Chrome.

For example, we have a table with 2 columns and 2 rows, but 1 cell will have `colspan="2"` and contain inner table with some content.

So, inner table content will affect on top-table cells widths.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzro9p6b/2/

```js
let maxChars = 20;
let str = 'z';
setDynamicContent(str);

setInterval(function() {
 if (str.length >= maxChars)
   str = '';
  str += 'zz';
  
  setDynamicContent(str);
}, 1000);

function setDynamicContent(value) {
 Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('dynamic')).forEach(function(el){
   el.innerHTML = value;
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
}

td[colspan="2"] {
  width: 100%;
}

.left-interesting-cell {
  background: #faa;
}

.right-interesting-cell {
  width: 100%;
  background: #aaf;
}

.inner-table td {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Why <code>left</code> and <code>right</code> cells are depends on dynamic content in Chrome 69?</h1>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table class="inner-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Some dynamic content:</td>
              <td class="dynamic"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-interesting-cell">left</td>
      <td class="right-interesting-cell">right</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641146/how-to-make-colspan-work-without-affecting-width-of-the-other-rows (not sure if I would call that an answer though...)

Comment: Actually, IE and Edge have same behavior:
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzro9p6b/3/ (JS fixed for IE)

Comment: @ippi Yes, it's my problem, thanks a lot!